# Errors Using Makefile to compile FLTK source code that uses images

Tags: c++, image, makefile, fltk

This is my Makefile:

```
# object files
OBJS = main.o

# compiler
#   since fltk-config --cxx displays the c++ compiler that was used to compile FLTK (g++)
#       we just use it instead of ... for safety purpose
#CC = g++-5 -std=c++11
CXX = $(shell fltk-config --cxx)

# debugging flag
DEBUG = -g

# flags used in compiling and creating object files
#   - fltk-config --cxxflags displays C++ complier options to use when compiling FLTK
#       source files
#       + can also be used when compiling non FLTK files
#   - Wall: tells compiler to print all warnings
#   - c: is needed to create object file, i.e. .o files
CXXFLAGS = $(shell fltk-config --cxxflags) -Wall -c $(DEBUG)

# flags used in linking
#   - fltk-config --ldflags displays the linker options to use when linking a FLTK app
#   - ??? fltk-config --ldstaticflags ... when lking a FLTK app to the static FLTK libraries
#LFLAGS = $(shell fltk-config --ldflags) -Wall $(DEBUG)
# may need below options when using images
LINKFLTK_IMG = $(shell fltk-config --use-images --ldstaticflags) -Wall $(DEBUG)
#LINKFLTK_IMG = $(shell fltk-config --use-images --ldflags) -Wall $(DEBUG)

# FLTK libraries 
FLTKLIB = -lfltk 

executable: $(OBJS)
    $(CXX) $(LINKFLTK_IMG) $(OBJS) $(FLTKLIB)

main.o: main.cpp
    $(CXX) $(CXXFLAGS) main.cpp 

clean:
    \rm *.o a.out
```

This is the code I'm trying to compile:

```
#include <FL/Fl.H>
#include <FL/Fl_Window.H>
#include <FL/Fl_Box.H>
#include <FL/Fl_Shared_Image.H>
#include <FL/Fl_JPEG_Image.H>

int main()
{
    // const int x = 505;
    const int x = 1000;

    //const int y = 340;
    const int y = 600;

    const int border = 10;

    // init the image library
    fl_register_images();

    // create a window and enclosed box
    Fl_Window *win = new Fl_Window(x+3*border, y+3*border);
    Fl_Box *box = new Fl_Box(border, border, x+border, y+border);

    // load jpeg image into memory and attach to the box
    Fl_JPEG_Image *jpg = new Fl_JPEG_Image("moon.jpg");
    box->image(*jpg);

    // done defining the new window
    win->end();

    // show the window and then delegate control to FLTK
    win->show();
    return(Fl::run());
}
```

This is the error:

```
/usr/bin/ld: cannot find -lpng
/usr/bin/ld: cannot find -lz
/usr/bin/ld: cannot find -ljpeg
/usr/bin/ld: cannot find -lXft
/usr/bin/ld: cannot find -lfontconfig
/usr/bin/ld: cannot find -lfontconfig
/usr/bin/ld: cannot find -lXinerama
collect2: error: ld returned 1 exit status
make: *** [executable] Error 1
```

After running the make command, the main.o file was successfully generated. So I guess there was something wrong with the linking process. 
Please send help.

Comment: As far as I remember, png, jpeg and related to them libraries (like libz) are not included into fltk library, so you have to link them manually

Answer (score 0):

Depends on what version of Linux you are using

SUSE - sudo zypper install

- libjpeg62-devel or libjpeg-devel
- libpng12-devel or libpng-devel
- zlib-devel
- xorg-x11-devel

Ubuntu variants - sudo apt-get install

- libjpeg62-dev
- libpng12-dev
- libx11-dev
- libxcursor-dev
- libxext-dev
- libxft-dev
- libxinerama-dev
- libxi-dev
- zlib1g-dev

It varies from system to system as to what the packages are called.  I don't know what they are called for redhat, debian or slackware.